# How to create a wizard in Salesforce

Tags: custom-object

Happy new year!

As I have just passed my 401 exam, and given that I have no previous actual SF experiecne, I am thinking of how to implement real-world scenarios in order to be competent. One of them, is how to implement a wizard.

In real world scenarios, there are many cases where we want to divide a whole process into several steps. And by clicking next, we can proceed to the next step. For example, in a credit card application, we need to first put in the basic information, then the contact details, then the supplementary cardholder's info, and submit the application after finishing all of them.

We can put everything in a single page but sometimes it will make the page too big and ugly. And I don't remember any feature in salesforce support that wizard-like implementation. One walkaround I can think of is to create some look-up relationships and make them mandatory. But is there a better way in doing this?

Thanks,
Lance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Lance have you looked at the visualforce developers guide. In Chapter 8 Advanced examples of this guide you can find nice example for creating a wizard....

[Click Here for the pdf link of the guide...](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/salesforce_pages_developers_guide.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for that. I have only read the first few chapters of that book that's why... Thanks.